# How to populate values of one row conditional of another row in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I inherited a data set coded in an unusual way. I would like to learn a less verbose way of reshaping it. The data frame looks like this:

```
# Input.
participant  = c(rep("John",6), rep("Mary",6))
day          = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(1,3), rep(2,3))
likes        = c("apples", "apples", "18", "apples", "apples", "7", "bananas", "bananas", "24", "bananas", "bananas", "3")
question     = rep(c(1,1,0),4)
number       = c(rep(18,3), rep(7,3), rep(24,3), rep(3,3))
df           = data.frame(participant, day, question, likes)

   participant day question   likes
1         John   1        1  apples
2         John   1        1  apples
3         John   1        0      18
4         John   2        1  apples
5         John   2        1  apples
6         John   2        0       7
7         Mary   1        1 bananas
8         Mary   1        1 bananas
9         Mary   1        0      24
10        Mary   2        1 bananas
11        Mary   2        1 bananas
12        Mary   2        0       3
```

As you can see, the column **likes** is heterogeneous. When **question** equals 0, **likes** conveys a number chosen by the participants, not their preferred fruit. So I would like to re-code it in a new column as follows:

```
   participant day question   likes number
1         John   1        1  apples     18
2         John   1        1  apples     18
3         John   1        0      18     18
4         John   2        1  apples      7
5         John   2        1  apples      7
6         John   2        0       7      7
7         Mary   1        1 bananas     24
8         Mary   1        1 bananas     24
9         Mary   1        0      24     24
10        Mary   2        1 bananas      3
11        Mary   2        1 bananas      3
12        Mary   2        0       3      3
```

My current solution with base R involves subsetting the initial data frame, creating a lookup table, changing the column names and then merging the lookup table with the original data frame. But this involves several steps and I worry that there should be a simpler solution. I think that `tidyr` might be the answer, but I don't know how to use it to spread values in one column (**likes**) conditional other columns (**day** and **question**).

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the data set above, you can try the following. You group your data by `participant` and `day` and look for a row with `question == 0` for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, participant, day) %>%
mutate(age = as.numeric(as.character(likes[which(question == 0)])))
```

Or as alistaire suggested, you can use `grep()` too.

```
group_by(df, participant, day) %>%
mutate(age = as.numeric(grep('\\d+', likes, value = TRUE)))


#   participant   day question   likes   age
#        (fctr) (dbl)    (dbl)  (fctr) (dbl)
#1         John     1        1  apples    18
#2         John     1        1  apples    18
#3         John     1        0      18    18
#4         John     2        1  apples     7
#5         John     2        1  apples     7
#6         John     2        0       7     7
#7         Mary     1        1 bananas    24
#8         Mary     1        1 bananas    24
#9         Mary     1        0      24    24
#10        Mary     2        1 bananas     3
#11        Mary     2        1 bananas     3
#12        Mary     2        0       3     3
```

If you want to use data.table, you can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, age := as.numeric(as.character(likes[which(question == 0)])),
            by = list(participant, day)]
```

NOTE

The present data set is a new one. Jota's answer works for the deleted data set.

Comment: Thanks! In my actual data frame, there are a couple of `question == 0` rows per participant, because there are several questions based on the `day` the participant was asked, which is another column. Is there anyway to adapt your code to deal with this?

Comment: @SolLago Would you be able to create a data set reflecting your point? That would allow SO users to help you more. One question. When question == 0, do you always have age? Or do you have other things?

Comment: @SolLago Thanks for the update. I will work on revising my suggestion.

Comment: yes, sorry! I tried to make the data set simple to make my question clear, and I ended up rendering the question more confusing. I have updated the sample data set now.I hope that it reflects the question better!

Comment: @SolLago Update done. Hope this will help your research project. :)

Comment: If you don't mind the warnings when `NA` gets inserted by `as.numeric`, you don't have to rely on `question`: `df %>% group_by(participant, day) %>% mutate(age = mean(as.numeric(as.character(likes)), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: ...or use regex to avoid warnings: `df %>% group_by(participant, day) %>% mutate(age = as.numeric(grep('\\d+', likes, value = TRUE)))`

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for your suggestions. The grep idea will do too.

Comment: @jazurro: This worked like a charm, thanks!  If it is ok with you, it might be better to delete the first part of the answer (before the EDIT). It might be confusing to other readers, as the original data frame is no longer there.

Comment: @SolLago I will edit my part depending on your revision. No worries.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the new example data:

```
# create a key column, overwrite it later
df$number <- paste0(df$participant, df$day) # use as a key
# create lookup table
lookup <- df[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(df$likes))), c("number", "likes")]
# use lookup to overwrite df$number with the appropriate number
df$number <- lookup$likes[match(df$number, lookup$number)]
#   participant day question   likes number
#1         John   1        1  apples     18
#2         John   1        1  apples     18
#3         John   1        0      18     18
#4         John   2        1  apples      7
#5         John   2        1  apples      7
#6         John   2        0       7      7
#7         Mary   1        1 bananas     24
#8         Mary   1        1 bananas     24
#9         Mary   1        0      24     24
#10        Mary   2        1 bananas      3
#11        Mary   2        1 bananas      3
#12        Mary   2        0       3      3
```

The warning about NAs be introduced by coercion is expected due to converting characters to numeric (`as.numeric(as.character(df$likes))`),.

---

If you're data are ordered like in the example, you can use `na.locf` from the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)
df$age <- na.locf(as.numeric(as.character(df$likes)), fromLast = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Jota! I can't really apply this solution, because the age of participants is not always the last value for each participant. (I just simplified my example for ease of presentation)

Comment: Thanks again! I am going to wait to see if there are other solutions, because I was already using a lookup table and I am hoping to find a way to avoid creating one. But this solution worked.